# C++: Using one type as another

Tags: c++, class, types

I'm using the Chipmunk physics engine for my C++ project.

Chipmunk has it's own vector, cpVect, which is nothing but a `struct { double x, y; };`

However I have my own operator overloaded Vector class in my project - and I'd like to use it just as a cpVect and vice-versa, without any conversions
(my `class Vector`'s only data fields are `double x, y` as well)

Currently I use this for implicit conversions (for argument passing, setting a Vector variable to a cpVect, etc.)

```
inline operator cpVect() { return cpv( x, y ); };
inline Vector( cpVect v ) : x( v.x ), y( v.y ) {}
```

This works for most things, but has a few problems - for example it isn't compatible for using arrays of the type Vector with cpVect arrays.

For that I currently have to do this:

```
Vector arrayA[123];
cpVect* arrayB = (cpVect*) arrayA;
```

- Is it possible by some way to use my Vector as cpVect and vice-versa? Data is identical with both structures, mine only has additional methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand you, you have this:

```
class Foo
{
  double x, y;
};

class Bar
{
  double x, y;
};
```

...and you want pretened that a `Foo` is actually a `Bar`, right?

You can't -- not without evoking [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).  No matter what you try, you will fall in to the great UB black hole.

- if you try to use a union, you'll evoke UB when you assign to `my_union.foo` and read from `my_union.bar`
- if you try to `reinterpret_cast` you'll evoke UB when to try to use the casted pointer
- if you try to use a C-style cast, you'll have the same problems as above

The problem is this:  Even though `Foo` and `Bar` *look* the same, *they are not the same*.  As far as C++ is concerned, they are completely different types, totally unrelated to each other.  This is a Good Thing, but it can also throw up some barriers that can seem to be artificial and arbitrary.

So, in order to do this without evoking UB, you need to convert.  You could make this nearly automatic, by simply adding a couple facilities to `Bar` (which I presume to be the one you wrote, not the one from the library):

```
class Bar
{
public:
  Bar(const Foo& foo) : x(foo.x), y(foo.y) {}; // lets you convert from Foo to Bar
  Bar& operator=(const Foo& foo) { x = foo.x; y = foo.y; return * this; }

  operator Foo() const { Foo ret;  ret.x = x; ret.y = y; return ret; } // lets you convert ffrom Bar to Foo
private: 
  double x, y;
};
```

Which will let you go from `Foo` to `Bar` and back again with little or no code.  Plus the compiler will optimize a lot of this away in release builds.

Comment: He was trying to make the conversion from array to array (or at least `vec*` ) work as well as individual object conversions. +1 for showing precisely why it's UB.

Comment: @Mark:  He can't without converting.

Comment: I can, and I have already done it with (cpVect*) someArrayOfVector;

Comment: @Alfred: then you are relying on undefined behavior doing a certian thing.  it certianly is not safe, nor is it portable.

Comment: And **why** is it undefined behaviour if `Foo` and `Bar` are both PODs, especially with the same memory layout (so `offsetof(Foo,x) == offsetof(Bar,x)` and `offsetof(Foo,y) == offsetof(Bar,y)`)? If you believe this is UB, please explain why would it be, because I believe both unions and reinterpret casts have well-defined operation on basic types and POD types.

Answer (score 0):

If both of those are simple PODs (no virtual functions etc), then a simple `reinterpret_cast` could save you here.

Comment: Disagree. The standard mentions that the result of a reinterpret cast is "implementation defined", which is *not* the same thing as "undefined" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior .

Answer (score 0):

Derive yours from theirs and fix-up the problems?  Seems simple enough to have 1000 traps. :)